# Solving arrayChange in CodeSignal Arcade Problem

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on the arrayChange level of Code Fights Arcade. This is the objective: You are given an array of integers. On each move, you are allowed to increase exactly one of its element by one. Find the minimal number of moves required to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from the input.

Example

For inputArray = [1, 1, 1], the output should be arrayChange(inputArray) = 3.

I have written this code in Python 3:

```
def solution(inputArray):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(inputArray)-1):
        if inputArray[i] < inputArray[i+1]:
            continue
        else:
            while inputArray[i+1] <= inputArray[i]:
                inputArray[i+1] += 1
                counter += 1
    return counter
```

It passes all the non-hidden tests, but fails the 7th hidden test. Can someone please help me figure out what bug my code has? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your problem with this solution.

```
def solution(inputArray):
    res = 0
    for i in range(len(inputArray) - 1):
        a = inputArray[i]
        b = inputArray[i + 1]

        if a >= b:
            steps = a - b + 1
            inputArray[i + 1] += steps
            res += steps
    return res
```

Comment: Tests passed: 12/20. Execution time limit exceeded on test 13: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.

Comment: Input/Output
[execution time limit] 4 seconds (py3)
[input] array.integer inputArray
Guaranteed constraints:
3 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 105,
-105 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 105.

[output] integer

The minimal number of moves needed to obtain a strictly increasing sequence from inputArray.
It's guaranteed that for the given test cases the answer always fits signed 32-bit integer type.

Comment: It is always better if you could provide all inputs and outputs.. Please check your problem with updated solution above.